# Load .pem certificate to Apple KeyChain

Tags: security, password, keychain, certificate

When I drag my .pem certificate to the Apple Keychain it shows me `"An error occurred. The content of this file cannot be recovered".` Also I tried to double-click the .pem file but show me the same error. I tried `sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain <certificate.pem>` but I get this error `SecCertificateCreateFromData: Unknown format in import.` Someone know how to solver this?
Note: the certificate that I want to store in my keychain is from AWS EC2 instance.